# Cómo obtener el valor de un arreglo en c# con wcf

Tags: c#, array, wcf

Tengo dudas, como puedo hacer para cuando el arreglo del recorrido llegue a la posición que quiero pueda seguir?

por ejemplo si tengo un arreglo de 5

int [] valores = new int[] {4,9,10,58,52};

entonces al momento de recorrer el arreglo quiero validar un objeto no todo.

por ejemplo si valores = a la posición 1 del arreglo (9)
se realiza lo que debe de hacer esta posición,

en caso de que no sea posición 1 y marque posición 0,2,3,4. simplemente finalice o marque error.

Comment: if (valores[x] == valorNumérico) o if (valores[x].equals("Texto"))  si es una cadena, donde x es la posición del array que deseas evaluar

Comment: Hola, y como puedo oponerle ? el tipo de dato que me arroja la variables es un array, no string, ni int :(

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te sirven los ejemplos. El código es totalmente funcional para que puedas probarlo y comprobar el funcionamiento

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        //damos dos opciones, operar con números en los arrays, o con letras
        Console.WriteLine("Si desea interacturar con números ponga 'n', con texto ponga 't' ");
        //recogemos la decisión
        String de = Console.ReadLine();

        //si tecleamos n, operaremos con números y entraremos en el if
        if (de.Equals("n"))
        {
            //pedimos la dimensión del primer array
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga el tamaño del primer array");
            //recogemos la dimensión
            int nA = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //creamos un array que recibe el resultado de dar valores al mismo llamando al método y enviando por parámetro su dimensión
            int[] arrayA = metodoDarValoresArray(nA);

            //pedimos la dimensión del primer array
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga el tamaño del segundo array");
            //recogemos la dimensión
            int nB = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //creamos un array que recibe el resultado de dar valores al mismo llamando al método y enviando por parámetro su dimensión
            int[] arrayB = metodoDarValoresArray(nB);

            //pedimos la posición en el primer array que deseamos evaluar
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga la posición a evaluar del array A");
            //recogemos el valor
            int eA = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //pedimos la posición en el segundo array que deseamos evaluar
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga la posición a evaluar del array B");
            //recogemos el valor
            int eB = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //evaluamos que ambas posiciones en cada array sean iguales
            if (arrayA[eA] == arrayB[eB])
            {
                //si lo es imprimimos los valores y el rsultado
                Console.WriteLine("El valor " + arrayA[eA] + " del array A, es igual al valor " +
                    arrayB[eB] + " del array B");
            }
            else
            {
                //si no es es imprimimos los valores y el resultado
                Console.WriteLine("El valor " + arrayA[eA] + " del array A, es distinto al valor " +
                    arrayB[eB] + " del array B");
            }
        }
        //si elegimos t, operaremos con texto y entraremos en el else if
        else if (de.Equals("t"))
        {
            //pedimos la dimensión del primer array
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga el tamaño del primer array");
            //recogemos la dimensión
            int nA = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //creamos un array que recibe el resultado de dar valores al mismo llamando al método y enviando por parámetro su dimensión
            String[] arraySA = metodoDarValoresArrayString(nA);

            //pedimos la dimensión del primer array
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga el tamaño del segundo array");
            //recogemos la dimensión
            int nB = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //creamos un array que recibe el resultado de dar valores al mismo llamando al método y enviando por parámetro su dimensión
            String[] arraySB = metodoDarValoresArrayString(nB);

            //pedimos la posición en el primer array que deseamos evaluar
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga la posición a evaluar del array A");
            //recogemos el valor
            int eA = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            //pedimos la posición en el segundo array que deseamos evaluar
            Console.WriteLine("Ponga la posición a evaluar del array B");
            //recogemos el valor
            int eB = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            //evaluamos que ambas posiciones en cada array sean iguales
            if (arraySA[eA].Equals(arraySB[eB]))
            {
                //si lo es imprimimos los valores y el rsultado
                Console.WriteLine("El texto '" + arraySA[eA] + "' del array A, es igual al texto '" +
                    arraySB[eB] + "' del array B");
            }
            else
            {
                //si no es es imprimimos los valores y el resultado
                Console.WriteLine("El texto '" + arraySA[eA] + "' del array A, es distinto al texto '" +
                    arraySB[eB] + "' del array B");
            }
        }
        //si no tecleamos 'n' o 't', no hay opción y finaliza el programa
        else{
            Console.WriteLine("Lo siento, esa opción no se contemplada, adios");
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
    //método que da valor a los arrays que recibe por parámetro la dimensión del mismo y devuelve el array completo
    public static int[] metodoDarValoresArray(int valores)
    {
        //creamos el array con el tamaño indicado
        int[] array = new int[valores];
        //pedimos los valores indicando cuantos vamos a pedir
        Console.WriteLine("Ponga Los " + valores + " valores del array");
        //creamos un buble
        for (int i = 0; i < valores; i++)
        {
            //vamos pidiendo valor a valor indicando su posición empezando en 1 y no la del array, que empezará en 0
            Console.WriteLine("El valor " + (i + 1) + " es:");
            //vamos guardando cada valor en cada posición del array según su iteración
            array[i] = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //retornamos el array
        return array;
    }
    public static String[] metodoDarValoresArrayString(int valores)
    {
        //creamos el array con el tamaño indicado
        String[] arrayT = new String[valores];
        //pedimos los valores indicando cuantos vamos a pedir
        Console.WriteLine("Ponga Los " + valores + " textos del array");
        //creamos un buble
        for (int i = 0; i < valores; i++)
        {
            //vamos pidiendo texto a texto indicando su posición empezando en 1 y no la del array, que empezará en 0
            Console.WriteLine("El texto " + (i + 1) + " es:");
            //vamos guardando cada texto en cada posición del array según su iteración
            arrayT[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //retornamos el array
        return arrayT;
    }
```